# GTID based replication is trying to reexecute what ever has been dumped on mysql

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

I am trying to replicate a cloudsql MYSQL database to a GCE VM and I am following this guide.
https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/replication/configure-external-replica

The error that I face is that is once I restore the dump and start my slave, the slave tries to execute the DDL commands that have already been dumped. In other words, the GTID based replication starts from 0.
What I expect is that it starts from the point where the dump has been taken.

What I am doing wrong here ?

I can see that I am getting the latest GTID set from the master. (left side is slave and right side is master).

[image: clo]

Comment: What's in your my.cnf file ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I have found out the issue.
The issue was that my dump file did not contain information about GTID from the source server. Because of this the destination has no idea about what GTID has been executed at the source.
So I must set gtid_purged to off when creating a mysql dump.
This will set the gtid_executed at the destination when restoring and ensure that there is not reexecution